# Triggering void constexpr at compile time?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++17, compile-time, static-assert

I have a `constexpr` function that groups many `static_asserts` for design contracts. I would like to call it at compile time, without having to create an unused `constexpr` variable.

Here is an example of what I currently have to do (c++17).

```
template<size_t N = 0, typename... Ts, typename F>
inline constexpr int tuple_for(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t, const F& func) {
    func(std::get<N>(t));

    if constexpr(N < sizeof...(Ts) - 1) {
        return tuple_for<N + 1, Ts...>(t, func);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

auto do_checks = [](const auto& t) {
    static_assert(has_some_method_v<decltype(t)>,
            "You need some_method");
    return 0;
}

[[maybe_unused]]
constexpr int i_am_sad = tuple_for(my_tuple, do_checks);
```

Is there any other way to achieve this behaviour? Maybe something new in c++17?

Thank you.

edit:
Note that as these checks are to be generalized, I believe having the asserts in a function is the right way to go here.

Comment: You don't really need any wrapper function, just put `static_assert` as is.

Comment: I should modify the example, this runs on a tuple of object. So in the actual code-base it needs to be.

Comment: why do you need to return? just call this function w/o return value.

Comment: @Kobi: Call it from where, I think is the problem

Comment: Exactly, you need to assign to a constexpr value for the method to be run at compile time. You can't just call the method inline your code for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use it in other constexpr context as `static_assert`:

```
static_assert((static_cast<void>(tuple_for(my_tuple, do_checks)), true), "!");
```

[Note]: the cast to `void` is to generalize, if you want to return class with evil overloaded comma.

Comment: Thanks, though not visually pleasing, this is prefect. What is the evil comma overload? Sounds interesting.

Comment: Oh my! That is so evil... I love it :D
Made a little macro helper, looks pretty clean.

Answer (score 0):

`static_assert` is a *declaration-statement*, so you can just plonk it in free space.

No need for a function.

This is precisely the use case for that. :)

Comment: The example is bad, I will edit it to resemble more what I am doing. 5mins :)